# How redirect to action of different controller with parameters of the target controller in grails

Tags: grails

I have a two domain classes Author and Book related as 1-to-many.  As I create a new book for a particular author, I want to redirect (upon clicking the save button) to the show action of the Author controller so as to show the full details of the particular Author with list of all books he authored.

```
class Author {
  String fistName
  String secondName

  static hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Book {
  String title
  String dateOfPublication
  //Author author

  static belongsTo = [author: Author]
}


//BookController
def save() {
    def bookInstance = new Book(params)
    if (!bookInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [bookInstance: bookInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [
      message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'),
      bookInstance.id])

    if(params.tempid){
      redirect(action: "show", controller: "author", id: params.id)
    }else{
      redirect(action: "show", id: params.tempid)
    }
}
```

However the code above did not redirect me as I wanted but instead executed the else statement with the flash message "Book not found with id null"

Below is this _book.gsp template rendered inside show.gsp of Author class.

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="book-data">
        <thead>
          <th class="sortable">Title</th>
          <th class="sortable">Date of Publication</th>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <g:each in="${authorInstance.book}" status="i" var="p">
            <tr class="prop">
              <td style="vertical-align: middle;" valign="top" class="value">${p?.title}</td>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle;" valign="top" class="value">${p?.dateOfPublication}</td>
             <td style="vertical-align: middle;" valign="top"><g:link class="btn btn-edit" action="edit" controller="book" id="${p?.id}"> Edit</g:link></td>
            </tr>
          </g:each>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

How do I get this right.?

Appreciate the help.

Edited: authorInstance.id changed to params.id

Comment: You're using `id: authorInstance.id` in the redirect but `authorInstance` isn't defined in your code.

Comment: I changed the authorInstance.id to params.id I thought this is supposed to work but it still produce this flash message "Book not found with id null" which is the result of the else statement. How do I access the right author instance.?

Comment: `if(params.tempid){
      redirect(action: "show", controller: "author", id: params.id)
    }else{
      redirect(action: "show", id: params.tempid)
    }` - this looks weird for me. If tempid is null or empty you do redirect using this value? What do you expect here? and what is tempid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect to your author instance after saving the `book`, you should send author's `id` within save request parameters. By default author id is contained in `params` map as `author.id`. 
So this should work:
`redirect(action: "show", controller: "author", id: params.author.id)`

Comment: Yes, it works but I have to get rid of tempid inside the if statement and replace it with params.author.id